# how to read json array from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

JSONObject,jsonarray cannot be resolved to a type

servlet:

```
    while(rs.next())
    {
    JsonObject jo=new JsonObject();
    jo.put("id",rs.getString(1));
    jo.put("sname",rs.getString(2));
    jo.put("gender",rs.getString(3));
    jo.put("address",rs.getString(4));
    jo.put("gmail",rs.getString(5));
    ja.add(jo);
    }
    request.setAttribute("jarray", ja);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("staff.jsp").forward(request, 
            response);
```

jsp:

```
   <% JsonArray ja= (JsonArray)request.getAttribute("jarray");
    for (int i=0;i<ja.size();i++) 
{
JsonObject rec = (JsonObject) ja.get(i);
System.out.print("<tr><td>"+rec.getInteger("id")+"</td> 
    <td>"+rec.getString("name")+"</td><td>"+rec.getString("gender")+"</td> 
    <td>"+rec.getString("address")+"</td><td>"+rec.getString("gmail")+" 
     </td></tr>");}
```

how can i read the json array in jsp.

Comment: What exactly is the point of copying resultset to json when you could just as easily use a simple Java class or a HashMap?

Comment: Have you imported them properly in JSP ?

Comment: i'm done  by importing the <%@page import="org.json.simple.*"%>

Answer (score 0):

Its typo error

Wrong:

```
JsonArray ja= (JsonArray)request.getAttribute("jarray");
```

Correct:

```
JSONArray ja= (JSONArray)request.getAttribute("jarray");
```